# Pasting copied contents from vim to an IDE inserts a new line

Tags: vim

I have a key mapping in my .vimrc file that allows me to copy an entire line to the external buffer:

```
"Yank Line
noremap , <C-V>g_"*y<CR>
```

When I paste to word, only the copied line is pasted, when I paste to Pycharm or Notepad++, an additional new line is inserted, how can I prevent this from happening. The only thing that should be pasted is the line that I yanked from vim and the cursor should remain on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug somewhere, but this seems to avoid it for me.

```
"Yank line
noremap , "*yg_
```

That said, thanks for letting me know a reason to use gvim instead of vim.  Too bad this couldn't be a regular vim feature.  (Because, of course, regular vim has no API to access the external to find out if it has a buffer.  Sigh.)